# Why does the connectedCallback not work for native HTMLElement(not custom elements)?

Tags: javascript, lifecycle, custom-element, mutation-observers

I know [connectedCallback](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_custom_elements#using_the_lifecycle_callbacks) is for custom elements. I wonder how to make the following snippet work:

```js
const div = document.createElement('div');
div.connectedCallback = () => console.log('connected!');
document.body.appendChild(div);
// how to make it print "connected!" here?
```

There are guys making [DOM/connectedCallback](https://docs.web-native.dev/play-ui/api/dom/connectedcallback) which utilizes the [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver).

MutationObserver should work for this scenario, but why does W3C not make connectedCallback work for HTMLElement? for performance?

I found there is a read-only property [isConnected](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/isConnected) but it's not helpful for detecting connected or not.

Answer (score 3):

Remember, HTML is backward compatible with previous versions

You would have to time-travel to HTML 1.0 (1993) to change behaviour into what you want.

New functionality is mainly added with **API**s. That is why it is called the ***Custom Elements API***..
it doesn't change HTML, Browsers **add** new functionality, you can call from JavaScript

Thus `connectedCallback` is a method of a **Custom Element** (which extends from HTMLElement)

So the only way to detect **mutations** on an HTMLElement is using the:  MutationObserver **API**

`connectedCallback` does not mean the lightDOM is ready; it fires on the **opening** tag; there could be a very large HTML structure **inside** which hasn't loaded and parsed yet.

Easiest method to wait till your lightDOM elements are created, is to continue when the EventLoop is empty:

```
connectedCallback(){
 setTimeout(()=>{  // or requestAnimationFrame()
   // lightDOM is ready now
 });
}
```

Comment: Wow that timeout trick is awesome. Now I'm curious: this is a typical scenario when XHR returns HTML containing custom-elements to inject with innerHTML: `connectedCallback` is fired too early to know of deepest tags (nested custom-elements are still simple `HTMLElement` at that time). Isn't there something else than a "trick" to properly handle custom-elements, and their nested CEs, on connection? Putting `setTimeout` in every `connectedCallback` feels quite cumbersome.

Comment: BaseElements like Lit, LWC, Stencil, provide callbacks that fire when the CEs lightdom is fully parsed; they use different patterns, promises, requestAnimationFrame. Dig into their open source code. It all boils down to one thing: Wait till the EventLoop is cleared. The connectedCallback firing on the opening tag is by design.. there could be many many many elements in lightDOM. setTimeout is not a trick, its JavaScript, and you only use it for CEs where you actually need to do something with lightDOM. The story is different for shadowDOM where you get SlotChanged events

Comment: Oh yeah, I always forget about the JavaScript thing. Thank you for the explanation.